# How to identify and remove newline and white spaces?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making an nsmutable array by separating a string by component it is causing a lot of new line and white spaces to be inserted in the array how to identify and remove them?

```
for (int i=0;i<contentsOfFile.count; i++) 
 {
        if(!([[contentsOfFile objectAtIndex:i]isEqual:@"\n"]||[[contentsOfFile     objectAtIndex:i]isEqual:@""]))
       [arrayToBereturned addObject:[contentsOfFile objectAtIndex:i]];
 }
```

this code which i am using cannot identify all new line charectors
thanks

Comment: i added an extra condition to check for \r\n it worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want an array without whitespace:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello, World!";
NSCharacterSet *separator = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSArray *stringComponents = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separator];
```

Answer (score 21):

To remove all extra space and \n from your string-

```
NSString* result = [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

than prepare your contentsOfFile Array.

Comment: -stringByTrimmingCharatersInSet only trims characters from the beginning and end of the string, use with caution.

Answer (score 10):

`stringByTrimmingCharachersInSet:` only removes desired characters from the end and the beginning of the string. To remove all occurences you should use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 version**

```swift
    let string = "Hello, stack overflow!"
    let components = string.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    print(components) // prints ["Hello,", "stack", "overflow!"]
```

Also regarding `string.replacingOccurrences`

```swift
    let string = " Hello, stack overflow     ! "
    let noSpacingsString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    print(components) // prints "Hello,stackoverflow!"
```