# How to remove non numeric characters from phone number in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, phone-number

This is my first attempt to make an ios app.

I'm using people picker to ask the user for a phone number, but when it retrieves with the code below, my `NSString *phone` apears like (0) 111192222-2222. I'm from Brazil and here the correct mask for mobile phone numbers is (01111) 92222-2222 (the 9 is optional, some numbers have others don't). How to fix this mask? Or remove it entirely?

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    ABMultiValueRef multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
    CFIndex index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiValue, identifier);
    NSString *phone = (__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, index);
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? If the NSString is `(0) 111192222-2222` what would you like it to be?

Comment: To remove the characters entirely it's probably simplest to simply iterate through them, copying them from string A to string B, and remove the ones you don't want.  Yes, you can probably use REs and whatnot, but why make the code more obscure?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6323208/60488

Basically:

```
NSString *cleanedString = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

For your case you may want to remove the characters "-", "(" and ")" from the character set.

Comment: Thank you, this is so more cleaner and quickier than what I was doing with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` and the others answers.

Comment: Just to add some info. After studying that code I would actually do `[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]` because its in the API and fits my needs!

Comment: Slick, I like the use of the invertedSet.

Comment: Very useful. I turned this into `+(NSString *)filterString:(NSString *)subject filter:(NSString *)filter{
 NSString *cleanedString = [[subject componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:filter] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
 return cleanedString;
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use few methods of NSString and NSMutableString as :

```
NSString *phone=@"(0) 111192222-2222";
//I'm from Brazil and here the correct mask for mobile phone numbers is (01111) 92222-2222
NSMutableString *editPhone=[NSMutableString stringWithString:[phone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""]];
editPhone=[NSMutableString stringWithString:[editPhone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]];

[editPhone insertString:@") " atIndex:6];


NSLog(@"%@",editPhone);//(01111) 92222-2222
```

Comment: This seems to be a very fragile approach. Prone to crashes if the phone number given is shorter than expected.

Comment: @JohanKool: Agree with you, But as per OP's question this is the solution. However if he asks then the solution can be altered with all sorts of valicdaions

Comment: In the question I've mentioned that **the 9 is optional, some numbers have others don't** so it would crash with certain phone numbers, but thank you for the solution. It DOES resolve that case.

Comment: @FernandoCrespo: Not an issue. you can count number of characters in the `phone`. If it is lesser then specified, definitely 9 is missing, you can go on to add a nine and then follow the logic as in answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are ways to solve this:

1. Using [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to remove anything but numbers. You
   can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478170/regular-expression-in-ios) to know how to validate phone number.
2. Write your own scanner to remove characters you don't need. [Remove
   blanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426194/how-to-identify-and-remove-newline-and-white-spaces) or [remove all but numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring).
3. Use the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html), write the
   `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method,
   check the replacement string if it is in the range of 0-9.

Hope helps.

Comment: Give you a point because of the nice aditions to my knowledge and because it answers my question, but the other answer below I find it more cleaner and quickier way to achieve what I was going to.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Regular expression to validate the phone number instead of killing myself to make a custom keyboard, which functions can be changed by iOS updates. So, allow all characters and validate inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5.0** solution

```
let purePhoneNumber = phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^0-9]", 
                                                       with: "", 
                                                       options: .regularExpression)
```

If you want to leave `+` sign in string, you can use regexp `[^0-9+]`.